# Is it possible to exclude pins at zoom levels

Tags: popup, leaflet, openstreetmap

Created my first map at
http://rich.littlebigfoot.org.uk/test7.html

I am plotting walks on the coast path (the yellow) and will be adding more walks and more information. However at current zoom I would like to exclude all the pins and only show them at zoom level 11?

Thanks

Rich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to hide some layers (pins/markers and/or vectors/paths) at some low zoom levels (like [0 to 10]), and bring them back at high zoom levels (like 11 and above)?

You would probably be interested in [attaching a callback](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#events) on map [`"zoomend"` event](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-zoomend), so that callback can remove or add your layers to the map depending on the current map zoom level, when the latter changes.

For example:

```js
map.on("zoomend", showOrHideLayers);

function showOrHideLayers() {
    if (map.getZoom() <= 10) {
        map.removeLayer(markers);
    } else {
        map.addLayer(markers);
    }
}

showOrHideLayers();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/116/

---

EDIT:

If your objective is to avoid overlapping of pins (markers), you might also be interested in "Clustering" functionality.

Have a look at available [Leaflet clustering plugins](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#clusteringdecluttering).

The most popular one is [Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) ([demo](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.markercluster/example/marker-clustering-realworld.388.html)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am also glad that you added the clustering element. That is very useful and answers an additional question I have. Huge thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what I am doing wrong but I have added the demo code to a new map to test the code and then integrate with the original map but I get a grey screen. http://rich.littlebigfoot.org.uk/test8.html Any ideas please?

Comment: Probably just need to remove the last part of the code which involves `currentZoom`. This was just a debugging aid.